# How to prevent shortcode preview from breaking in tinymce editor?

Tags: shortcode, tinymce, wp-editor, plugin-tinymce

I am creating visual preview for shortcodes (just like captions). I have don't most of the parts but my preview html is getting broke by the editor when post is saved.

I have investigate it further and will try to give as much information as possible.

**Replacing Shortcode**

I am replacing shortcode by hooking into `BeforeSetContent` event. Here is how the event callback looks like

```
//replace from shortcode to an image placeholder
editor.on('BeforeSetcontent', function(event){

    if ( event.format !== 'raw' ) {
        console.log(event.content);  // log before shortcode replacement
        event.content = replaceShortcodes( event.content );
        console.log(event.content); // log after shortcode replacement
    }

});
```

**Below are some logs and observation I have made**

So, from the log before shrotcode replacement. I have noticed something weird. Take below shortcode for example.

If I have a shortcode like this:

```
[shortcode attr1="my attr" attr2="my attr 2"]
    a bunch of contents
    <h1>A h1 tag</h1>
[/shortcode]
```

In the log it becomes

```
<p>[shortcode attr1="my attr" attr2="my attr 2"]</p>
<p>a bunch of conents</p>
<h1>A h1 tag</h1>
<p>[/shortcode]</p>
```

**Notice**, how shortcode tag is wrapped with `<p></p>` tags. I guess somehow *line brakes are being added to each line of shortcode that is why `<p>` tags are being added. But Can't figure out from where!*

So, I was curious how content for wp caption looks like. And sure enough caption doesn't have this problem.

Example

```
[caption id="attachment_205" align="alignnone" width="370"]<img class="size-full wp-image-205" src="http://localhost/l/factory/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/10882100_885482111484562_5965805158604571190_n.jpg" alt="khkjh" height="389" width="370"> khkjh[/caption]
```

**Function for Converting and Restoring Shortcode and Preview HTML (simplified)**

These are the function being used for converting and restoring shortcodes.

```
function replaceShortCodes(content){
     content = content.replace( /\[block([^\]]*)\]([^\]]*)\[\/block\]/g, function( all, attr, con) {
                return html_block( 'block', attr , con); // returns html content
            });
    return content;
}

    function restoreShortcodes(content ) {

        var $tmp = jQuery('<div>', {
            html: content
        });


        $tmp.find('.content-block').each(function () {
            var $this = jQuery(this);
            var attr = decodeURIComponent($this.data('sh-attr'));
            var content = decodeURIComponent($this.data('sh-content'));
            var shortcode = '[block' + attr + ']' + content + '[/block]';
            $this.replaceWith(shortcode);
        });

        content = $tmp.html();
        return content;
    }
```

Now, How do I prevent tinymce to wrap around `<p>` tags on shortcode?

Comment: Maybe there is something in shortcake source https://github.com/fusioneng/Shortcake that may be helpful.

Comment: Very interesting indeed! I wish I had it 10 days ago. Lots of custom coding could've been avoided. oh well! :)

Comment: Going back to the problem in hand. I am suspecting jQuery `replaceWith()` perhaps causing the problem.

Comment: Honestly: I didn't read all your code ;) FYI shortcacke is a feature plugin, i.e. it may be included in core in future releases...